# How do i represent an image through CAML?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

How do i represent an image through CAML? I have a list and im trying to create a list instance by adding data through CAML

```
 <Data>
      <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Field Name="Title">Promotion 2</Field>
          <Field Name="Promotion Image">/SiteCollectionImages/PR.gif</Field>

        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<Field Name="Promotion Image"><![CDATA[[<IMG SRC="/SiteCollectionImages/PR.gif"/>]]></Field>
```

Comment: Yea, I forgot the IMG element.

Answer (score 1):

this did the trick:

```
<Field Name="Promotion Image"><![CDATA[<IMG SRC="/SiteCollectionImages/PR.gif"></IMG>]]></Field>
```

thanks Magnus

Comment: You should click the tick next to Magnus' answer. Gives him a bit of reputation and you may get a badge :D